# error EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code 1, address=0xcc)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have jumped into a iphone app project.

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)GET:(NSString *)URLString
                   parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
                      success:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject))success
                      failure:(void (^)(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error))failure
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.requestSerializer requestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:[[NSURL URLWithString:URLString relativeToURL:self.baseURL] absoluteString] parameters:parameters error:nil];

// Below line throws error EXC_BAD_ACCESS (Code 1, address=0xcc)

    __block NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * __unused response, id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            if (failure) {
                failure(task, error);
            }
        } else {
            if (success) {
                success(task, responseObject);
            }
        }
    }];

    [task resume];

    return task;
}
```

I have checked api returns proper data.
I have tried Enable Zombie Objects also.

I am new to swift and iOS development can someone please guide what should i check next.

Comment: This is Objective-C code, not Swift code. I edited the tags to help you find the right audience.

Comment: Have you tried create exception breakpoint yet? This code might not be where the problem happen

Comment: how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolve this issue only by debugging the source code and re-analyze my logic.

Below are some reference that help me lot.

EXC_BAD_ACCESS means that message was sent to a point in the memory where there’s no instance of a class to execute it. Thus “bad access”.

You will get EXC_BAD_ACCESS in 3 cases:

1. An object is not initialized
2. An object is already released
3. Something else that is not very likely to happen

That’s already a good starting point. Start using the debugger, if you recently added a new object to the class you’re working on, put a breakpoint at the line before the freshly added object is used for the first time and check the values in the debugger.

What’s happening most though is that you will be sending a message to an overreleased object – i.e. object that is gone from the call stack. In this cases everything (and indeed everything) you will get in the console will be just :EXC_BAD_ACCESS

This is because the object is gone, there is no information what class was it, or what source file or anything else.